# ELB not able expose 2 services

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have one spring-boot and one react app deployed on 1 ec2 instance.

I am trying to expose both to public internet via and ELB.
Spring-boot runs on 8080 port. eg localhost:8080/v1/api**
react app runs of 3000 port. eg. localhost:3000

I would like to expose them both using Elastic Load balancer on aws.
I have 2 target group created.

one maps / --> this is mapped to the springboot app.
another one maps to /index.html

But it not able to resolve.

Comment: Have you considered using [S3 static website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) for the React side of you app?  It's very simple and there isn't a need for load balancing, etc.  It would make this problem much easier.

Comment: This is not a static website, cant host on s3.

Comment: The React side is.  When you build a react app you can place the entire `build` directory in S3.